# Angular js wont install on my machine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, installation

I have node.js installed on my machine, I have version: v0.12.0 installed. Following instructions when I use sudo npm install I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.6.0
npm ERR! path /Users/aston.haigh/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/aston.haigh/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/aston.haigh/Projects/astonhaigh.co.uk/npm-debug.log
```

Ive tried clearing the node cache, updating node and havent had any luck, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing nodejs npm and grunt gives errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280713/installing-nodejs-npm-and-grunt-gives-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to fix the issue when i uninstalled node and then reinstall using homebrew. P.s really good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqMIyTH9wSg